# Change name encryption algorithm?

Tags: encfs

EncFS offers 2 different modes for encrypting filenames: "block" and "stream". I left the defaults and it chose "block". Now I'm discovering the filepaths it has created are too long for Windows to handle. Can I change the encoding to "stream" or do I have to delete everything and start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think the easiest would be to create a new EncFS folder with the options you want, then mount it & your old folder and copy/move the files into the new folder.

I'm don't think it's possible to change those options on an existing EncFS folder. So basically the "delete & start over" option.